# Is collapse of wavefunction actually relative?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, wavefunction-collapse, schroedingers-cat

I suddenly had an odd philosophical question. Suppose there are two people and the Schrodinger's cat experiment is done, such that after placing the dynamite and cat within the box and waiting for a period of time, one out of the two people open the box and sees what happened to the cat. But, they do not tell the 2nd person the cat's fate. In such a case is the wavefunction of the cat collapsed for the 1st person who knows what happened to the cat, but still spread out for the 2nd person who doesn't know it? Precisely what is the cat's wavefunction? Is it relative to the observer, therefore?

Comment: These may help - [Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why](https://www.facebook.com/veritasium/videos/parallel-worlds-probably-exist-heres-why/339179977597625/) and [Sean Carroll explains: what is the many-worlds interpretation?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_xqNDII--Q). They don't answer your question, but they explain things.

Comment: Check [Wigner's friend paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend)

Comment: If there is *any* measurable difference between the world where the cat is dead, and the world where it is not, the superposition is over for any part of the universe that has interacted with that measurable difference. If person 1's pupils are dilated 1/1000 of a mm more in one world than another, then the superposition is over and there is no more wave function interference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to account for how information spreads between systems using quantum mechanics that means the wavefunction doesn't collapse, since collapse is an ad hoc kludge that attempted to account for lack of interference on macroscopic scales (i.e. - on the scales of objects we can see as opposed to small systems like atoms). This idea is commonly called the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics. A macroscopic system like a cat interacts with its environment as well as measuring instruments or an observer's eyes. For example, air molecules and photons interact with the cat, as do the sides of the box. When information about the cat spreads to other systems this prevents the cat from undergoing quantum interference as a result of a process called decoherence:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

This happens very rapidly, less than $10^{-23}s$, for an object with a mass of 1 gram:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072

This means that on the scale of everyday life the MWI claims that reality looks a bit like a collection of parallel universes. The state of a system in a particular universe is called the relative state.

Information about the state of a system has to be carried in physical objects and so spreads at or below the speed of light. So if an observer has not yet interacted with that information his relative state, properly understood, doesn't reflect that information:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328

Answer (score 1):

No, the wave function collapse is not relative. If I make a measurement, then the probability distribution for a new measurement changes, regardless of who makes that new measurement, or with what knowledge. For instance, if I measure the energy of an atom, I thereby collapse the atom into an energy eigenstate, and any new observer measuring its energy will find it to be in that same eigenstate in which I found it (since energy eigenstates stay energy eigenstates). It does not matter if they have any knowledge of my measurement.

If it weren't so, quantum encryption wouldn't work. The whole point of quantum encryption is that we can know wether someone listened (measured our photons' spins) just by making enough measurements of our own, since the listener influences our probability distribution by collapsing the wave functions of the photons we use to communicate.