# Is the superposition of a particle before the collapse of the wave function a relative effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, superposition, wavefunction-collapse

From the perspective of an electron in the double slit experiment, does the "rest of the universe" that it is disconnected from behave in the same manner as the electron does in our view? As in, is the world around it, from the electrons point of view, as a closed, separate system to be interpreted the way we see the electron? Is the effect relative? From the electrons perspective, could it be in a "collapsed"-state and consider only the universe around it to be in a superposition? I hope the question makes any sense, because I am really curious and a little confused about the whole thing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you think the electron to be a closed, separate system and not a transfer of energy from the start point to the end point of the experiment (i.e. an integral part of the whole).

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/749500/28512

Answer (score 2):

In mainstream physics the electron is a quantum mechanical entity and in the accepted theoretical models of [Quantum Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) the QFT predictions of the experiments with electrons have been verified experimentally many times .

> from the electrons point of view,

This is modeling the electron as a classical mechanics particle, i.e. going to the center of mass of the electron . This has no meaning in the QFT mainstream calculations of the electron interactions, would just make the calculations more difficult.

In QFT the electron is a point particle, whose (x,y,z,t) four vector is not predicted by QFT, only the **probability** distribution  of finding the electron at (x,y,z,t) can be mathematically predicted. This means that only an accumulation of electrons under the same boundary conditions is theoretically predicted to be  checked by measurements.

> From the electrons perspective, could it be in a "collapsed"-

the term "collapsed" is a sloppy way of describing the measurement of on electron's (x,y,z,t) , i.e. the *mathematics* of the QFT wavefunction allows to do the calculation and define the (x,y,z,t) of the wavefunction used to calculate the probability distribution.

There is no way to identify this "collapse"  with a particular electron in the experiment.It describes the mathematics of arriving at the probability distribution, and the fact that a  new wavefunction is needed after the measurement and the new boundary conditions.

The accumulation of the electrons behavior in the same boundary conditions and energies is the only thing that can be predicted and experimentally tested.

> could it be in a "collapsed"-state and consider only the universe around it to be in a superposition?

thus the answer is no.

Comment: it would be useful to read the wavefunction postulate http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html

Answer (score 0):

Wavefunctions don't collapse. Rather, when a system undergoing interference spreads information to the outside world through an interaction that process prevents interference. This effect is called decoherence:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072

For human beings decoherence appears to happen very rapidly because we interact with the outside world very rapidly compared to the scales of space and time over which we think. As a result, we don't have to worry about whether we're going to experience diffraction when walking through a doorway.

An electron doesn't think so in some sense the world doesn't appear like anything to an electron. However, in many of electron's interactions with the world quantum effects are important because decoherence effects take place over a scale of space and time that is larger than or similar to the scales of the electron's interactions. For a paper about decoherence in electron interference experiments see:

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/ab8efc/pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Under the [Everett Interpretation](https://cqi.inf.usi.ch/qic/everett_phd.pdf), if you treat the observer as a wavefunction, then each component of an orthogonal superposition cannot see or interact with any other. So as far as the electron is concerned, it is in only *one* position, because it cannot see all the other components who *also* think they are in only *one* position.

We could tell if the different parts of a single electron's wavefunction could see one another because electrons are *charged*. If there was any interaction between the different parts of their wavefunction, they would *repel* themselves, and their motions would be different.

For the same reason the different parts of an electron's wavefunction don't interact, neither do the different parts of a human observer's wavefunction. Each orthogonal component acts independently, as if none of the others existed. It's because the Schrodinger equation is *linear:* A sum of solutions is also a solution.

The splitting into a superposition of orthogonal components can also be understood as the result of *normal modes of vibration*. See here for a hand-wavy sketch of the maths: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/731652 You can see from that that the non-interacting systems we start with are symmetrical - each considers the other to be in a superposition. When the systems interact, the superpositions get *correlated* so each component of the electron's superposition corresponds to a component of the observer's superposition. Again, the situation is symmetric. The electron thinks it has interacted with the observer and collapsed it into 'an observer seeing an electron *here*'.

Of course, in this interpretation, nothing has actually collapsed. All the alternative outcomes are still there. They're just paired up, and mutually invisible.